# Trying to get a shorter navbar with correctly scaling navbar-brand offset

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I just can't figure out a way to implement a shorter navbar with correctly scaling navbar-brand offset.

When I try to use a percental value for the max width or the margin-right of the navbar it completely disturbs the offset of the navbar-brand.

When I try to use a fixed value for the margin-right and then try to change the margin-left from the .navbar > .container .navbar-brand I get better results but sometimes the .navbar-brand makes a short jump.

Here I have the bootply code with my two different tries.
http://bootply.com/86804
I hope someoen can help me.

Answer (score 0):

**update**

Between a screen width of 768 en 991 pixels (the small grid) i find this:

[image]

Is the above what you call a jump?

Possible solutions:

1. set your grid breaking point to 991px
2. only apply the  `margin-right:100px;` of your .navbar-else above the 991px
3. add a break in your.nav-brand:

   @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {

   .navbar-brand > strong:after {
       content:"\a";
       white-space: pre;
   }

   }
4. make your font smaller below 992 px

etc.

--end update
The examples on http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar don't wrap the .navbar-header in a .container.

Try to set:

```
.navbar
{
   width:50%;
}
.navbar-header
{
   padding-left:80px;
}
```

see: http://bootply.com/86839

Comment: With your solution the navbar-brand doesn't align with the content container when I resize the window. That is the reason why I tried putting it into a container or am I missing something. http://bootply.com/86874

Comment: wrap the complete navbar in a .containter this will make the navar size (50%) relative to the container

Comment: Then the complete navbar is relative to the container. I want the navbar aligning to the left side of the screen and only the navbar-brand aligning the the left side of the container. exactly like this  http://bootply.com/86897  But it is not always aligning. It has little jumps in it when I resize the window.